In Antd + HTML, how can I use the icons such as user-outlined?
I'm working on an Antd+HTML job and found that the Icons don't work.
When I use  it says [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: user-outlined
And When I use  it says [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: a-icon
I tried to import icons-vue but it says i can't do that outside a module
then I tried
const { Icon } = antd;
...
components: {
   AIcon: Icon,
},

And also no luck
